# Iteratively inserting column and rows to 2d numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The next 2d numpy is given.

```
prv = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
```

I want to go through `prv` lines iteratively, perform some calculationa and insert the results into a to a new column at new numpy. The values from the previous numpy need to be save with the calculation context, so the size of the new numpy depends on the results obtained from the function.

For example, performing the following operation:

```
for i in prv:
    new_line = calc_something(i)
```

The results of `calc_something(i)` may be something like this:

```
[[1,2,7],
 [1,2,6],
 [1,2,3],
 [3,4,3],
 [5,6,9],
 [5,6,7]]
```

That is, the results of `calc_something(i)` for each row can be a list that stored in the last column  while the first and second columns preserved the values of the first numpy in the results context.

For example test data for `calc_something(i)` can be:

```
def calc_something(i):
    if i[0] == 1:
        b = np.array([7,6,3])
        return b
    if i[0] == 3:
        b = np.array([3])
        return b
    if i[0] == 5:
        b = np.array([9,7])
        return b
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `calc_something` for all rows and store them in a list
2. Use `numpy.hstack` to combine original array and the results

```
#Example usage
import numpy as np
prv = np.zeros((10, 2)) # original array

results = []
for x in prv:
    results.append(calc_something(x))

results = np.reshape(np.array(results), (prv.shape[0], 1))

combined = np.hstack((prv, results)) # combine the two array
```

Comment: The original array ```prv = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])```, Contains one instance per line. It is impossible to know in advance what the result of the function ```new_line = calc_something(i)``` will be. Can you elaborate on how this solves the problem?

Comment: @ElhananSchwarts 1. I did not understand "prv Contains one instance per line". Did you refer to each row as an instance? 2. With my solution `calc_something` needs to be a number. Store the numbers in list, change to `numpy array` then use `hstack`. If theres a chance of result of `calc_something` not begin a number, I cant help you

Comment: I edited the question and added a possible example of performing the function ```calc_something(i)``` . Its can be assume that the function return a number.

Comment: Can you check if the solution you gave will work with the function ```def calc_something(i):``` above